# Best way to load QObject in DLL during runtime

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dynamic-linking, qobject

I have encountered some trouble with **dynamic** loading of Dll containing **QObject** without loosing the **signal/slot** mechanism.

I ended up with something working well but I thought that maybe I went totally overkill and missed something that could have helped a lot... I am going to go through the main steps I took to my final code.

Ok, lets start with context.

I have became quite familiar with using Dll containing QObject derived in a "static way" with properties that I can directly use in qml code :

```
class MyLIB_EXPORT MyLib : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( int  property  READ getProp WRITE setProp NOTIFY propChanged )
    public : 
        int  getProp     ( void  );
        void setProp     ( int p );
    signals :
        void propChanged ( void  );
}
```

linked to project with these line in .pro :

```
INCLUDEPATH +=   $$PWD/../MyLib/
win32: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../MyLib/ -lMyLib
```

I have been quite happy with this way until now...

Problem is, thess Dlls become mandatory for the program to start and now I need to be able not to include a dll and have the program run with just disabling this part.

The reason I want to be able not to include this dll file are :

- Space usage for user ( no need to ship useless dll )
- Startup time ( each dll loading at start takes more and more time )

I started to look at this glorious mechanism of retrieving function pointer from dll using QLibrary.

```
typedef void ( *t_init )( void );

t_init f_init = (t_init) QLibrary->resolve( "init" );
```

This quite heavy because I have to do that with every function but I'm okay to pay the price.

In the end I found some way to use a "handler"

```
// Create handle to keep a pointer to an instance of the class MyDynamicLibHandler
typedef MyDynamicLib* MyDynamicLibHandler;

// Function that creates an instance of MyDynamicLibHandler.
MYDYNAMICLIB_EXPORT
MyDynamicLibHandler getHandle  ( void );

// Function that allow to use the object referenced by the handle
MYDYNAMICLIB_EXPORT
int getMyValue ( MyDynamicLibHandler handle ); // return handle->getMyValue
```

At some point I had a working example of a dynamic library that was loaded during runtime by a static library.

BUT

I could not get the QT signals mechanism to work...

The only solution I have found so far is to use another Object, the MySignalEmiter, that would be shared by the two classes and would be capable of emitting signal when MyDynamicLib needs it and StaticDynamicLoader can connect it to something else.

```
class MYSIGNALEMITER_EXPORT MySignalEmiter : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    void    emitMyValueChanged ( void ){ myValueChanged() ; }

signals:
    void    myValueChanged      ( void );
};
```

StaticDynamicLoader connect the signal to Q_PROPERTY signal:

```
m_signalEmiter = f_getSignalEmiter( m_handle );
QObject::connect( m_signalEmiter                      ,
                  &MySignalEmiter::myValueChanged     ,
                  this                                ,
                  &StaticDynamicLoader::valueChanged  );
```

MyDynamicLib instanciate MySignalEmiter and use it to "emit" signals

```
MyDynamicLib::MyDynamicLib()
{
    m_mySignalEmiter = new MySignalEmiter;
}

MySignalEmiter* MyDynamicLib::getSignalEmiter()
{
    return m_mySignalEmiter;
}

void MyDynamicLib::setMyValue( int val )
{
    m_myVal = val;
    m_mySignalEmiter->emitMyValueChanged();
}
```

In the end I have something working and I'm ok with those "tricks" but I can't help to think there must be other ways around.

**Am I missing something ? Are there better ways to dynamically link QObject ? Are there problems with the way I did it**

*[The whole code is on github if you feel like reading it all or testing it](https://github.com/buckTarle/DynamicLib)*.

This is my first post on stack so tell me if my post is not correct I will try to edit it.

Comment: Have you seen Plugins? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#the-low-level-api-extending-qt-applications (See the section about `QPluginLoader`)

Comment: I did try at some point but could not find many examples. I'll have look !
Does this allow to load dynamically not at the start of the program ?

Comment: Not quite; the plugins are loaded when you construct `QCoreApplication`. However, plugis allow you to make your QObjects optional. I presumed that your object is optional since you said _"Space usage for user ( no need to ship useless dll )"_

Comment: You are right, the main goal here is to get optional dependencies that wont crash my program if missing. 
I am playing with Plugin and Interface right now, trying stuff out

Comment: Good news! I was mistaken: With `QPluginLoader`, you can load your DLL at any time you want.

Comment: Ok, so I have tried to play with QPluginLoader. If I am not missing something, using this do not simplify so much the use of a DLL. I end up with same amount of work to "wrap" my dll with a QPluginLoader that I had with QLibrary ...
I will continue to investigate these options soon.